# Varnish how to set different TTL for ESI and how to verify the same

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have an ESI section on a page. I want different TTL of ESI than the whole page. 
I have two queries

1. Where do I specify the TTL configuration for various ESIs on a page?
2. How can I verify varnish cache hit or miss per ESI?

Please give your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Easiest way to split is to define a url pattern to match pages and a url patten to match the snippets included with ESI. for example with prefixes or suffixes.
   Something like:

   > ```
   > sub vcl_fetch {
   >   if (req.url ~ "^/includes/"){
   >     set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
   >   } else {
   >     set beresp.ttl = 24 h;
   >   }
   > }
   > ```
2. You can run varnishlog on the server and reconstruct what varnish did. Otherwise check the access.log on the target server.

Comment: Hi Boris, thanku for your reply. I am using the same code you gave. however, even after the expired ttl, page is not getting refreshed from backend!

Comment: Can the ESI response contain a header that would set the TTL for the esi request? Or, can the TTL be set in the <esi:include> tag?

Comment: The ESI response can set a header, and you can read that header in the beresp.http. variable. With that you can then set the ttl if you want that.